# IdentityServer - User API Access

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

The premise is that we want to build an API that determines its output based on the user that is authorized through IdentityServer4. An an example, user "John" (a user that exists in our product) will want to start using the product's API. So he registers access through our IdentityServer and off he goes. Based on his roles and rights in the product, the API will return information and data only accessible by John. The API knows it's John because John has somehow authorized himself through IdentityServer.

tl;dr below

That's where things get fuzzy. Typically, our clients use their own software to communicate with our API's and get data from them. As there is no user interactivity there, the implicit or hybrid flows don't work (to my understanding). So we're left with a client machine and an API that wants to know who the user is so it can determine what data to return. The resource owner password grant seems a poor choice because we want to avoid having to send the user's credentials just to get a token and seems like a bad practice in general.

So we're not sure what options are left. I'm certain it's possible to use some sort of manual mapping that registers what client is used by which user but this falls outside of the OAuth/IdentityServer and requires manual tinkering, which is something we'd like to avoid.

**tl;dr** - What is the best method to have non-interactive clients authorize as the user(s) they represent without the need for the resource owner password grant? Does it even exist?

**update** - We're going to try and implement our own grant validator(s) for our scenario. If we're successful I will post an additional update with the details.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, you don't have much choice but to pass user information as part of the request body. You may try to obfuscate it in some ways, e.g. signing it with a certificate.

Your scenario can be seen as the "trusted client", therefore a redirect flow (hybrid, implicit) is not needed, and this is perfectly fine for machine-to-machine(api) use.

User information is still publicly available in any JWT result from hybrid or implicit (just go to https://jwt.io/ to decode it), so it matters what you're using to identify the user.